# alter for loop to skip record with missing value

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

When I run the code below, I get the error below.  What seems to be happening is that for some _place records in my good_df dataframe there are no hcat with the stf_id and no entries in the goodsellers field.  The goodsellers field has a concatenated string of values that are separated by pipe.  So since it can't split on pipe since there aren't any values it throws an error when it hits the missing record.

I'd rather modify the code so it just skips to the next _place record, can anyone suggest how to do that?

```
Code:

stf_id = good_df['hcat'].unique()
place = good_df['_place'].unique()

for stf_id in stf_id:
    for place in place:
        print("%s | %s" % (place, stf_id))
        goodsellers = good_df[(good_df['hcat']==stf_id) & (good_df['_place']==place)]['goodsellers'].squeeze().split("|")

        display_th_pan(goodsellers[:10], ds)


Error:

AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-5656b6495fa9> in <module>()
      2     for place in place:
      3         print("%s | %s" % (place, stf_id))
----> 4         goodsellers = good_df[(good_df['hcat']==stf_id) & (good_df['_place']==place)]['goodsellers'].squeeze().split("|")
      5 
      6         display_th_pan(goodsellers[:10], ds)

/data2/453/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   3612             if name in self._info_axis:
   3613                 return self[name]
-> 3614             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   3615 
   3616     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: can you paste first few lines of `good_df` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for stf_id in stf_id:
    for place in place:
        print("%s | %s" % (place, stf_id))    
        try:
            goodsellers = good_df[(good_df['hcat']==stf_id) & (good_df['_place']==place)]['goodsellers'].squeeze().split("|")
        except AttributeError:
            print("skipped to the next _place record")
            continue
        display_th_pan(goodsellers[:10], ds)
```